# Android Realm - RealmObject returning after deletion

Tags: android, realm

I'm running in to an issue where I delete a RealmObject (and confirm its gone using StethoRealm), but when I create and save a new RealmObject with the same variable value, the deleted RealmObject reappears along with my new RealmObject.

With the below object - I delete the myObject1 by matching the 'id', but when I create a new MyObject myObject2 with the same 'name' both objects appear in my realm

Any tips on why this might be happening?

Example:

```
public class MyObject extends RealmObject {

@PrimaryKey
private String id;

private String name;

// getters and setters

}
```

## Edit

Delete call

```
@Override
public void deleteMyObjectById(final String id, final OnDeleteMyObjectById callback) {
    Realm realm = new MyRealmConfiguration().getDefaultRealm();

    final RealmResults<MyObject> myObjects = realm.where(MyObject.class).equalTo(RealmTable.MyObject.ID, id).findAll();

    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            myObjects.deleteAllFromRealm();

            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onSuccess();
            }
        }
    });
    realm.close();
}
```

Add call

```
@Override
public void addMyObject(MyObject myObject, OnSaveMyObjectCallback callback) {
    Realm realm = new MyRealmConfiguration().getDefaultRealm();
    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(myObject);

            if (callback != null) {
                callback.onSuccess();
            }

        }
    });
    realm.close();
}
```

Comment: I dont know the way you use Real to delete and create new object but you should use a realm instance for deleting and then get a new instance of Realm for creating, if you use an existing realm instance to create, it's still reference to old DB then deleted object still appear

Comment: The above code is not enough to investigate this problem. Could you add some code includes deleting and creating objects?

Comment: `where I delete a RealmObject (and confirm its gone using StethoRealm), but when I create and save a new RealmObject with the same variable value, the deleted RealmObject reappears along with my new RealmObject.` all of that code should be included in the question!

Comment: Edit: added save/delete methods

Comment: Thanks @Naz. Do `deleteMyObjectById` and `addMyObject` run on main thread?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure as to how you are deleting your objects. The way I'm deleting them (and it works) is...

```
final RealmResults<UserCredentials> credentialResults = realm.where(UserCredentials.class).findAll();

realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
    @Override
    public void execute(Realm realm) {
        credentialResults.deleteAllFromRealm();
    }
});

realm.close();
```

Of course, you are using MyObject instead of UserCredentials, and you aren't deleting everything of that type, but it should be similar enough. Try using **executeTransaction** and **realm.close()** if you aren't already.

Comment: Exactly as I'm doing, except I am getting my realm instance before I get my RealmResults  
`Realm realm = new MyRealmConfiguration().getDefaultRealm();`

Comment: Wait, so you're using your own configuration, but getting the default Realm instance? You have to instantiate Realm differently if you're using a custom Realm config

Comment: My MyRealmConfiguration overrides getDefaultRealm to return my custom config

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. get the instance inside transcation method and delete. i have been using this for one of my app. and it works fine with deletion process

```
 Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                RealmResults<MyObject> myObjects = realm.where(MyObject.class).equalTo(RealmTable.MyObject.ID, id).findAll();
                myObjects.deleteAllFromRealm();
            }
        });
```